# How to pass div value to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to pass value of the div with `id="monthlyPayment"`, that takes value after filling the inputs and calculations on js-side, to php and send it to email. I was trying to do it with AJAX and DOM but I have a little experience so it did not work out, maybe someone can help me!

```js
function credit() {
    var loanTerm = document.getElementById('loanTerm').value * 12;
    var interestRate = 0.09858333;
    var creditSum = document.getElementById('carPrice').value - document.getElementById('anInitialFee').value;

    var monthlyPayment = (parseFloat(creditSum) * parseFloat(interestRate) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + parseFloat(interestRate), -loanTerm))).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('monthlyPayment').innerHTML = "Ваш ежемесячный платеж: " + monthlyPayment;
    document.getElementById('sent').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="functions.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="mail_sender.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" placeholder="укажите ваше имя"><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="укажите ваш email"><br>
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="укажите ваш телефон"><br>
        <input type="text" id="carPrice" name="carPrice" value="" placeholder="укажите цену автомобиля"><br>
        <input type="text" id="anInitialFee" name="anInitialFee" value="" placeholder="укажите первоначальный взнос"><br>
        <input type="text" id="loanTerm" name="loanTerm" value="" placeholder="укажите срок кредита"><br>
        <div id="monthlyPayment"></div>
        <button id="sent" style="visibility:hidden;">Send to email?</button>
    </form>
    <button id="credit" onClick="credit();">Calculate</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```php
<?php
    $recipient = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Письмо с сайта";
    $name = $_POST['firstName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $carPrice = $_POST['carPrice'];
    $anInitialFee = $_POST['anInitialFee'];
    $loanTerm = $_POST['loanTerm'];
    $monthlyPayment = $_POST['monthlyPayment'];
    $mailBody = "Имя: $name \n Email: $email \n Телефон: $phone \n Цена автомобиля: $carPrice \n Первоначальный взнос: $anInitialFee \n Срок кредита: $loanTerm \n Ежемесячный платеж: ";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody);
    echo "Mail sent.";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it a hidden input field.
I suppose you don't want it to be displayed to the user, so the code would be

```
<input name="monthlyPayment" id="monthlyPayment" style="display: none;" disabled>
```

But keep in mind that the user can always modify this. So, when receiving data in PHP, *never trust user input*.

Comment: True, but an input of `type="hidden"` would be even better. That's what they're there for!

Answer (score 1):

`monthlyPayment` is a div element and not a form element so it isn't passed with the $_POST data.

Change the `<div>` to an `<input>` and you'll be able to pick it up in `$_POST['monthlyPayment']`.

Add a `readonly` attribute to the input and the user won't (normally) be able to edit it.